# unable to run migrate.exe in Teamcity

Tags: entity-framework, teamcity-9.0

I have the following very simple powershell script

```
packages\EntityFramework*\tools\migrate.exe /?
```

when I run this script in a powershell console it shows the expected output ( lists all the possible parameters of migrate.exe )

However, when I run the same script from Teamcity using a powershell build step or even a command line build step, I get the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrME9.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to copy the text of the error into the question, images aren't searchable for other people who may have the same error in future, and they can't be read by screen readers.

Comment: OK, so when you say you run it in a console, is that on the same machine as TeamCity? Is your TeamCity service running under a system account like Local Service or System, or under an actual user account? Have you tried using the full path to migrate.exe rather than a relative path? The second line in your error message does indicate it could be path related.

Comment: after opening services.msc I see 3 services which have "TeamCity" as part of their name. 1. TeamCity Build Agent, 2.TeamCity Server, and 3.TeamCity Instance
inside service msc under "Log On As" column, for 1 and 2 I have .\Adminstrator and for 3 I have Network Service

Comment: used full path and got the same error

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue...any updates?